# I'm trying to download the audio using DownloadManager in Android Studio but it's downloading an unknown file

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have a link.
If I download this link directly using DownloadManager, it will send back an unknown file.
But when I run this link on the web it shows the download as mp3. [running this link on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh6SD.png) 
I want to download the audio directly without running it to WebView.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems like a streaming file.  What your need do is to find a Stream-Downloader in Android.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Add below library...

```
implementation 'com.github.esafirm:rxdownloader:2.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'
```

Now call below function

```
public static void download(Context context, String url, String name){
    RxDownloader rxDownloader = new RxDownloader(context);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url); // Path where you want to download file.
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);  // Tell on which network you want to download file.
    request.setTitle(name + ""); // Title for notification.
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);  // This will show notification on top when downloading the file.

    File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)+"/"+YOUR_FOLDER_NAME)
    if(!file.exists()) file.mkdris(); //make sure you have storage permission


    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_MUSIC, YOUR_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + name);

    //rxDownloader.download(request).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new CoreMySave1(Core.this, this, file2.getAbsolutePath(), isOnlyAudio));
    rxDownloader.download(request).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            Log.d("====", "onSubscribe");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(@NonNull String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("====", "onError :: " + e.getMessage());

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d("====", "onComplete");

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the issue? Please verify you have storage access and folder is available in music directory.